# Targeting in NME - Demo project cannot converted to, for example, JavaScript - Target error

Tags: compiler-errors, haxe, target-platform, nme

I'm playing with the interesting tool NME which is a combination of Haxe and Neko.

I like the idea that it is possible to target to different languages but this seems not right?

I have downloaded the examples and run perfectly when targeting NME, but when i select another target, for example Javascript, i get the following error (in FlashDevelop):

```
Running process: C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\fdbuild\fdbuild.exe "F:\Personal\NMEHaxe\nme\examples\HandlingKeyboardEvents\HandlingKeyboardEvents.hxproj" -ipc 5a2362fe-f815-45c2-95d7-cbb9f230408a -version "2.10" -compiler "C:\Program Files (x86)\Motion-Twin\NME\haxe" -notrace -library "C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Library" -target "flash"
Building HandlingKeyboardEvents
haxe -cp Source -cp "C:/Program Files (x86)/Motion-Twin/NME/haxe/lib/nme/3,5,5/" -cp Export/flash/haxe -lib nme -lib actuate -js F:/Personal/NMEHaxe/nme/examples/HandlingKeyboardEvents/project.nmml -D nme_install_tool -D web -main ApplicationMain -swf-version 11
C:\Program Files (x86)\Motion-Twin\NME\haxe\lib\nme/3,5,5/format/display/MovieClip.hx:9: characters 0-28 :
```

**You can't access the flash package with current compilation flags (for flash.display.Sprite)**

```
Build halted with errors (haxe.exe).
Done(1)
```

If this is really impossible, the tool does not make sense to me because why using this when you cannot target another target. Or do I missing something in the whole Haxe/NME story? Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: Please provide the example code you are trying to compile, html5 target does support most of the api features.

Comment: It is with the default demo's, this one is the HandlingKeyboardEvents demo.

Comment: There are many default demos. Are you using the latest versions?? Try and run command "nme create piratepig" and then cd into "cd ./piratepig" and run "nme test html5"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, replace `flash.` with `nme.`, for example:

```
nme.display.sprite;
```

This compiles the code but does not run via FlashDevelop. It overwrites the `project.nmml` file with JS code when target is JavaScript.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: This question does not make sense, please start a new question and be as specific as you can so someone can reproduce your problem.